# punctuation, spelling, and orthography tags

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

We currently have tags for [punctuation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation), [spelling](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling), and [orthography](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography). Is there any overlap there, and when should we be using each tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling relates to how to write one or more words with letters and diacritics. Punctuation relates to the symbols that indicate the structure and organization of written language, as well as intonation and pauses to be observed when reading aloud. Clearly, both spelling and punctuation are aspects of orthography, but orthography also includes other elements such as hyphenation, capitalization, and emphasis.

Clearly there's an overlapping, but the three tags can coexist: questions about orthography in general could be tagged with two tags: [orthography](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) and the tag associated to the specific aspect of orthography addressed in the question. For example, spelling-related questions could be tagged with both the [spelling](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) and [ortography](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortography) tags; simmilarly, questions about punctuation could be tagged with the [punctuation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) and [ortography](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortography) tags. Those questions relating to the other aspects of orthography (hyphenation, for example) can be tagged with [orthography](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) and a (possinly new) [hyphenation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) tag.